# How to create and run a service in CentOS?

Tags: php, laravel, centos, cpanel, laravel-5

I created a Laravel application and I want to run a php artisan command to monitor the email queues. So, I created a service using the below linked article.

http://thecpaneladmin.com/adding-services-to-chksrvd-for-monitoring/

Now I can see my service is enabled in "Service Manager" in CPanel. But, I cannot see the service running the Process manager section.

The service I have written is as follows,

```
service[laravelqueue]=x,x,x,/usr/bin/php /home/laravel/artisan queue:listen --timeout=0 --tries=3 --daemon
```

The command I need to run as a service:

```
php artisan queue:listen --timeout=0 --tries=3 --daemon
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In process manager look for PHP process.

Comment: I couldn't find PHP process in the process manager. Maybe the way I have implemented it is wrong. Can anyone help me out with this please ?